# How do I get transparency to work with the Principled BSDF shader?

Tags: materials, node-editor

How do I get the Cycles Principled BSDF shader to support a base color image such as a 32bit png with alpha or a tga with an alpha channel, and get the transparency to work. I don't see anywhere on the Principled BSDF shader that handles transparency.

Without success, I have tried:

- Properties Editor>Render tab>Film rollout>Transparent
- Properties Editor>Material tab>Settings rollout>Viewport Alpha (changing to other than Opaque).
- Adding a Transparent BSDF and Diffuse BSDF after the base
  color image node and using a Mix Shader to combine them.

Comment: For Blender 2.8+, to get the Alpha property to work on the Principled BSDF shader go to Material Properties > Settings and set the Blend Mode to either Alpha Hashed or Alpha Blend.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The principled shader can be combined just like any other shader.
Adding a Transparent shader and using the alpha channel to control the mix will make the black sections of the Alpha become transparent.

[image]

Read also: 
[Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

Comment: What if the alpha is not an image texture but the base color of the principled itself?

Comment: @quimnuss Please ask this as a new question. You can include a link to this post in it.