# B&W Opacity map

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do I use a black and white opacity map like this one in Blender Cycles? I have searched and tried everything I have found and cannot get it to work. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get transparency to work with the Principled BSDF shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/how-do-i-get-transparency-to-work-with-the-principled-bsdf-shader)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a screen shot of how I use images like this. I plug the image into the mix factor between a transparency shader and a diffuse or emission shader (whatever you want it to be) and then where it is white, you will see the solid, black is transparent.
[image]