# How do I create a Jacquard-Textile with an unrepetitive pattern?

Tags: modeling, texturing

For an ongoing project I need to create a textile object in Blender that has a jacquard air mesh. See the attached reference image (Size of fabric on ref.Picture: 100mm x 100mm). The jacquard has a non-repetitive pattern. The object has a size of 1900mm x 900mm. I do not have a photo of the final sized jacquard, so the image texture is not a good choice. All I have is an Adobe Illustrator vector drawing. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much and best regards Silvana

[image: Jacquard1]

How can I define the exact position of the pattern. for example if I have a pattern like the following on the picture:
[image: Jacquard]

How can I increase the displacement? (the holes should be deeper)

[image: hole displacement]

Comment: Hi :). Where *exactly* are you stuck? Making the different textile materials, or applying the pattern?

Comment: https://simonthommes.gumroad.com/l/Knittr

Comment: @JachymMichal I'm a Blender beginner, so I'm struggling with both. I don't really know how to get started. I have the model built, but now I need to apply the pattern to the model. Since the pattern is defined exactly as in picture 2 of my question and I don't have a picture of the jacquard - how can I make the pattern as simple as possible using only my Adobe Illustrator drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image seems to have three different textures in a randomish distribution.  Blender can handle this with a procedural or mixed (procedural & image textures) material.  In this example Mix RGB nodes and Color Ramp nodes use Noise Texture nodes to create masks for three separate areas similar to your image:

[image]

Here the Voronoi Texture node, Musgrave Texture node, and Magic Texture node represent the three weave patterns -- they can be replaced with appropriate image textures or different procedural patterns:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. I added some details on my question above. How can I define the exact position of the pattern?

Comment: From what you've commented above you have a specific model you want to apply this to -- have you UV unwrapped it?  Search on "UV unwrapping" "Blender" if you don't know what that is.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: somehow I managed to do the displacement with the UV Editor. Please see updated question above for the picture. At the moment it looks quite ok. But can you tell me how to increase the displacement (the holes should be deeper).

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark, but you shouldn't edit your question to essentially add a new question, it hampers the usefulness of our question/answer to others.  In your added graphic I see that the Displacement Node's Scale is 1.0, you might want to increase that.  But if you need actual holes you could use your displacement map thru a Color Ramp into the Fac input of a Mix Shader node for a Transparent BSDF and your Principled BSDF:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/how-do-i-get-transparency-to-work-with-the-principled-bsdf-shader

Comment: In my above comment my Scale recommendation is wrong -- details in my answer to your next question here:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253553/how-to-combine-displacement-and-material/253558#253558