# How to combine displacement and material

Tags: shaders, transparency, uv-image-editor, displacement

I need to combine a transparent displacement with a material. See Screenshot:
[image: nodes]

This is the result I need to achieve:
[image: Jacquard]

My problem is the mix shader. Either the material is perfect and the holes are almost not visible or reversed. It is a jacquard -> so a 3D mesh with a textile surface/material.
Can anyone help me with that?

Here my Blender-File:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to pack the images into your Blend file (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and re-upload it so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Hi :). Any reason you're using a displacement output to mix in a transparency? You're also not using the displacement input at all :)

Comment: If the answers below didn't answer your question then pls let us know what else you need.  And thanks for posting your blend file, but John Eason's right, the texture map you're using isn't packed into it.  You also might consider posting a .blend that has only what's needed to see (and hopefully fix) the problem -- only that model (or a stand-in), only that material, lighting, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Don't *mix* displacement with a shader.
Use the dedicated Displacement input.

For transparency use the Alpha channel input in Principled Shader.

<sup>example of material shader + with transparency + displacement</sup>
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this example the Magic Texture node is standing in for the grayscale image texture to be used for both a Displacement map and a Transparency map:

[image]

Note the two different Color Ramp nodes used to make the "deep" parts of the Displacement input also the transparent parts of the input for the Mix Shader node's Fac socket, each adjusted for best effect.  Your mileage may vary, of course -- you'll probably need different positions for the Color Ramp sliders. And in the upper Color Ramp using a very light gray instead of white for the left slider will make the visible part of the material a smidge more transparent, which could make it look more like fabric.

Edited to add:  I forgot something important - in either the Sidebar (n-panel) > Options tab > Settings > Surface > Displacement field, or the Properties area > Material Properties tab > Settings > Surface > Displacement field, the field should be set to either Displacement Only or Displacement and Bump.  **Without that the Displacement node *won't displace.***  With that my earlier recommended Scale value is very wrong, you want something much lower (in this example I used 0.032).  Also please note the Plane and Cube have a Subdivision Surface Modifier using the Simple algorithm at 8 levels -- although that would normally be far higher than needed, Displacement (unlike Bump) requires a mesh dense enough to displace, and you're working with a detailed fabric.

[image]